# can i specify a queue name when generate shared access signatures (SAS) for my azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

here is the docs that describe how to [Constructing a Service SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Constructing-a-Service-SAS?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

the document says, you can specify a table name , so that the sas can only access that specific table.

Can i do the same thing with queue, so the sas can only access that specific queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i do the same thing with queue, so the sas can only access that
>   specific queue?

Sure you can! Take a look at the code below:

```
    static void GenerateSasForQueue()
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        var queue = client.GetQueueReference("queue-name");
        var sasPolicy = new SharedAccessQueuePolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
            Permissions = SharedAccessQueuePermissions.Add | SharedAccessQueuePermissions.Read |
            SharedAccessQueuePermissions.Update | SharedAccessQueuePermissions.ProcessMessages
        };
        var sasToken = queue.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasPolicy);
        var sasUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", queue.Uri.AbsoluteUri, sasToken);
    }
```

This code will generate a SAS Token on the queue named `queue-name` in your storage account with all permissions valid for 2 hours from the date of SAS creation.

Comment: i tried that code, it generate a sas like this:
?sv=2015-12-11&sig=XGU%2BzyaZtNOAL339OgzOsTMav5ULcxeuI0Q1jrLRxG0%3D&st=2017-06-02T17%3A03%3A58Z&se=2017-06-02T19%3A18%3A58Z&sp=raup
in this sas, i can not see any where showing the queue name, if i use this sas to access another queue, would be rejected?

Comment: just made a test, yes, it works.  so how does this work? the queue name is in side of the signature?  my thought is the sas is really created at the client side, has to be somewhere to specify the queue name.

Comment: `the queue name is in side of the signature?` - that's correct. When the signature is calculated, it uses queue name.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a queue-specific SAS token, go to Storage Browser (so, not the "Shared Access Signature" menu item). Then select Queues and from the three dots of the specific queue you can start generating a SAS. Give it the expiry times etc, as you would normally do.
That generated SAS token is only valid for that specific queue.